# Change .aspx on a SPView

Tags: development, list, list-view

I'd like to create a SPView for my list that points to a complete custom aspx page. And I need to do that through c# code.
Even if I could just override the AllItems.aspx in a Visual Project Project, that would be fine. (on a preexisting SPList)

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to create a new view and then add some javascript to the page, via a CEWP, to redirect the user to your custom page.

Comment: I guess that's what you have to learn with Sharepoint. Very often there just isn't a solution, only workarounds :(